# Java - How to handle Exception Handling in a Looping Switch Statement

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement, do-while

I'm just trying to figure out how to implement Exception Handling in a Switch Statement which will then loop me back to the menu for input again. What I am trying to catch is String input where it should be Integer. I think I'm close but can't find any help in previous questions here, the output I'm getting when I enter a String is a neverending "Please enter an integer". Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        System.out.println("\n*** Please make a selection from 1 to 3 and press ENTER: ***\n");
        System.out.println("1. Test1");
        System.out.println("2. Test2");
        System.out.println("3. Test3");
        
        
        boolean continueLoop = true;
        
        do
        {
            try
            {
                int selection = input.nextInt();
                
                if(selection <=0 || selection >= 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nInvalid Selection - Please Try Again!\n");
                    
                }
                
                switch(selection)
                {
                    case 1:
                    System.out.println("Test1");
                    continueLoop = false; 
                    break;
                    
                    case 2:
                    System.out.println("Test2");
                    continueLoop = false; 
                    break;
                    
                    case 3:
                    System.out.println("Test3");
                    continueLoop = false; 
                    break;
                    
                    default:
                    continueLoop = false; 
                    
                    
                }//end switch
            }//end try
            catch(InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) 
            {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
            }
        }while ( continueLoop );
    }
}
```

Comment: After `input.nextInt();` fails, the bad input is still sitting in stdin. You need to consume with a call to `input.nextLine();` or `input.next();`

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp. Thanks very much, adding "input.next();" on the line after my print command within the Catch did the trick!